# Logic gate AND with a bug

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, logic-gates

I'm doing an AND gate in a circuit using 2 transistors BC337-40. I'm also using an LED in series and a 680 Ohms resistor.

I expected the LED to light up only when both transistor bases were HIGH. But when the second transistor is short-circuited it closes the circuit with the base of Q2 and current passes from the Base to the Emitter.

How can I go around this with BJT transistors?

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Sd1X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Or this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483677/led-current-at-output-of-and-gate?rq=1.

Comment: I just noticed the photograph shows the base connected not to +, but to the other side of R1 - adjust the schematic diagram?

Answer (score 1):

No way to get around the base current flowing through the terminal biased in forward direction, the emitter if not in reverse operation.
Limit the base current to sane values - TTL used almost 1 mA, if memory serves.
Design the rest of the circuit such that this base current does not impede operation of the circuit.
Here, base resistors of about 4.7 kΩ and a 680 Ω resistor from Q2 emitter to ground should do the trick.
If you place R1 in series with the LED, you even get a TTL level output,
but the input will not be compatible to any 5 V logic family.
For lack of voltage amplification, such "gates" will not work in deep networks: to build a 42 input gate, you would need 6 levels at least.